# Passing custom objects to Windows Mobile 6 Application

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile

I have a website (lucky me) and in this website the data access is achieved using custom classes like this...

```
IList<Thing> things = ThingFactory.GetAll();
```

and

```
Thing thing = ThingFactory.Get(1);
```

...and everything is working just fine.

I've now been asked to develop a Windows Mobile 6/CF3.5 application (Windows Forms).

The application will pull down data from our server and store it in a SqlCe/Compact database for use offline. Any changes to the data (client or server) needs to be synchronised next time the device is docked.

Can someone please offer me some guidance on how I send data to and from the Mobile Application?  My main question being is the following possible....

```
[WebMethod]
public IList<Thing> SyncThings(IList<Thing> thingsThatTheMobileChanged)
{
    ThingFactory.SavedChangedThings(thingsThatTheMobileChanged);

    return ThingFactory.GetAllThatHaveChangedSinceLastSync();
}
```

...and how is that consumed on the client/mobile side?

I have looked around at some other similar questions posted on SO, but I'm just not getting the answers I'm after!!

Many thanks for any help offered,

ETFairfax

Comment: Your description says Windows Mobile 6, and the subject Windows Mobile 5. That just gives us the OS.  What framework/language are you building the client application in? Knowing that will help us answer you.

Comment: Hi Will, it should have been mobile 6 using Compact Framework 3.5 in C# (I will update that in a mo).  Since posting the question, I have been looking at Sync Services for ADO.NET.  Is that worth a look???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to serialize your list of objects and return array of bytes
PDA will take this array of bytes and deserialize it.

Comment: This is exactly how I ended up doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Syncing between SQL Server databases to great success.  This will update your database whenever it's connected without any requirements from you, the developer. What this means for you is that instead of the application pulling new data,the application needs to just get objects from the database.  You will probably want some sort of timestamp records in your database records so you know when they've changed.
[Disclaimer: I wrote my mobile app that talked to Compact SQL Server around 6 years ago; back when a mobile device was still called a PDA]

Comment: Hi erict, thanks for the reply.  Can you tell me a little more about the technologies/techniques you used to Sync the data? Also, how flexible was the sync to customise? For instance, if you had to get a specific section of data rather than the whole table?

Comment: It is doable to only have a portion of a table sync'd with the database.  The whole thing is SQL Server Replication, read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx
Your entire chore becomes a database issue.  One coding detail left is how to deal with collisions, i.e. both the master database and a user update the same record -- how should replication resolve that...